# Precision when splitting sum in partial sums in threaded applications

Tags: math, pthreads, precision, numerical-methods

I am writing C++/C code that uses float type to do sums. I know I could use double or long double but right now I am testing float. I compare 2 implementations, one single threaded where the whole sum is carried out in one go, and another threaded implementation where partial sums are made and then summed at the end when all threads are done. I am getting differences of the order of magnitude of 0.0001 even with very small test series (say 20 numbers in all, just to test). This surprises me. It is understandable to get differences but I expected them to be smaller. One could suspect a bug, however, the 2 implementations give consistent results up to 3 decimals. What do you think, is this reasonable, or should I look for a bug? Which implementation is more accurate?

Comment: It is difficult to say without have seen your source code.

Comment: It is difficult to say without knowing the magnitude of the numbers summed and the sum; if all the numbers concerned are in the thousands then a difference of 0.0001 is the best you can hope for.

Comment: The order of magnitude is 0.1 none of the numbers is higher than about 0.9

Comment: To sort this out, let the single threaded version perform the summation identically: accumulate the two halves separately then add them. Now you can compare to the split version.

Answer (score 2):

Sum value for float numbers depends on summing order. Probably you have met this issue.

One could provide better precision (diminish numerical errors) if summation process starts from smaller magnitude values.

More advanced approaches exist - [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) etc

Comment: Thank you, very intresting, I wasn't aware (ashamed...). I suppose it is difficult to achieve in the long run, as it would force me to always re-order data, still it is definitely worth keeping in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: @tony_s_99  Kahan summation doesn't require reordering

Answer (score 0):

I understand you would like to use float for your testing. But to confirm you have bug or not I would just change your variables to double give it one try and check result. If result for double is OK it means you have no bug. If result for double also differs much you have a bug. 
Then after doing a test you can go back to float. 
 By the way I think it is possible to get such difference even with only 20 numbers.

Comment: Thank you, I'll just try that.